# Check if dictionaries are equal in df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a df, in which a column contains dictionaries:

```
      a    b    c   d
0     a1   b1   c1  {0.0: 'a', 1.0: 'b'}
1     a2   b2   c2  NaN
2     a3   b3   c3  {0.0: 'cs', 1.0: 'ef', 2.0: 'efg'}
```

and another dict:

```
di = {0.0: 'a', 1.0: 'b'}
```

I want to add a new column with 'yes' in it when d=di, and 'no' or 'NaN' or just empty when it's not. I tried the below but it doesnt work:

```
df.loc[df['d'] == di, 'e'] = 'yes'
```

The result would be:

```
      a    b    c   d                                    e
0     a1   b1   c1  {0.0: 'a', 1.0: 'b'}                 yes
1     a2   b2   c2  NaN
2     a3   b3   c3  {0.0: 'cs', 1.0: 'ef', 2.0: 'efg'}
```

Anyone being able to help me here?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df['new'] = df['d'].eq(di).map({True:'yes',False:''})
```